# Send sparse matrix numpy through API request efficiently

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I need to send some huge matrices (full of 0s) in **several server to server communications through http and JSON.**

I'm working with numpy and scipy in **Python 3.x.**

**Is there any standard way to tool to do it?**

I guess I could send indexes and, in some way, rebuild the matrix in the second server to get the full matrices but I would like to avoid using custom code to reinvent the wheel.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest approach is just [pickling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html), but the dedicated functions are probably more efficient!

Here some demo using python3 and scipy's dedicated [save_npz](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.save_npz.html) function (which uses compression by default), wrapped with [BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) (to not use files; do it in memory).

I'm not touching the JSON-part, but this seems trivial (as we prepare a string here), especially for people doing web-stuff.

Code:

```
import io
import scipy.sparse as sp

mat = sp.random(100, 100, density=0.001)
print(mat)

# mat to serialized-string
tmp = io.BytesIO()
sp.save_npz(tmp, mat)
tmp.seek(0)  # back to start
str_ = tmp.read()
print(str_)

# serialized-string to mat
tmp_ = io.BytesIO(str_)
mat_loaded = sp.load_npz(tmp_)
print(mat_loaded)
```

Output:

```
(59, 11)      0.137877385333
(7, 36)       0.137729960685
(94, 14)      0.0951372931412
(3, 80)       0.235640993271
(56, 54)      0.504472012678
(8, 14)       0.657124520803
(22, 92)      0.951629612278
(81, 18)      0.733232743418
(39, 16)      0.228000113182
(17, 15)      0.127198226805
b'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\xd5}gK\xc9\xb8\xd0xH\x00\x00\x00\\\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\x00format.npy\x9b\xec\x17\xea\x1b\x10\xc9\xc8\xe0\xc6P\xad\x9e\x92Z\x9c\\\xa4n\xa5\xa0n\x13j\xac\xae\xa3\xa0\x9e\x96_TR\x94\x98\x17\x9f_\x94\x92\n\x12wK\xcc)N\x05\x8a\x17g$\x16\xa4\x02\xf9\x1a\x9a:\n\xb5\n(\x80+\x99\x81\x81!\x1f\x8a\x01PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\xd5}gKR\xab(\x82I\x00\x00\x00X\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x00\x00shape.npy\x9b\xec\x17\xea\x1b\x10\xc9\xc8\xe0\xc6P\xad\x9e\x92Z\x9c\\\xa4n\xa5\xa0n\x93i\xa2\xae\xa3\xa0\x9e\x96_TR\x94\x98\x17\x9f_\x94\x92\n\x12wK\xcc)N\x05\x8a\x17g$\x16\xa4\x02\xf9\x1aF:\x9a:\n\xb5\nH\x80+\x85\x81\x81\x01\x84\x01PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\xd5}gKy\xea\xf44\x99\x00\x00\x00\xa0\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00data.npy\x9b\xec\x17\xea\x1b\x10\xc9\xc8\xe0\xc6P\xad\x9e\x92Z\x9c\\\xa4n\xa5\xa0n\x93f\xa1\xae\xa3\xa0\x9e\x96_TR\x94\x98\x17\x9f_\x94\x92\n\x12wK\xcc)N\x05\x8a\x17g$\x16\xa4\x02\xf9\x1a\x86\x06:\x9a:\n\xb5\n\x08\xc0%\xb3,/\xec\xfb\xd2\x83\xf6%/2\x96)-<h\xefp\x7f\xf5\xabWQ;\xec\x0f\x88\xdc|]\xady\xce\xbe)\xb2\xadv\x91\xca\x03\xfb\x97\x8f\x8f3h\xb1?\xb5?\xdat\xe5\xe3\xfe\xe2w\xf6\xe5\x87W5/){n/\xc1|v\x92\xb4\xfeY{\tY9\x01\x0e\x8f\x03\xf6\x00PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\xd5}gK\x96\xb0\xb4\xa3]\x00\x00\x00x\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00col.npy\x9b\xec\x17\xea\x1b\x10\xc9\xc8\xe0\xc6P\xad\x9e\x92Z\x9c\\\xa4n\xa5\xa0n\x93i\xa2\xae\xa3\xa0\x9e\x96_TR\x94\x98\x17\x9f_\x94\x92\n\x12wK\xcc)N\x05\x8a\x17g$\x16\xa4\x02\xf9\x1a\x86\x06:\x9a:\n\xb5\n\x08\xc0\xc5\xcd\xc0\xc0\xa0\x02\xc4|@\x1c\x00\xc4fPv\x0c\x10\x0b\x01\xb1\x00\x10\xf3\x031\x00PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\xd5}gK\r\xef\xd0@_\x00\x00\x00x\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00row.npy\x9b\xec\x17\xea\x1b\x10\xc9\xc8\xe0\xc6P\xad\x9e\x92Z\x9c\\\xa4n\xa5\xa0n\x93i\xa2\xae\xa3\xa0\x9e\x96_TR\x94\x98\x17\x9f_\x94\x92\n\x12wK\xcc)N\x05\x8a\x17g$\x16\xa4\x02\xf9\x1a\x86\x06:\x9a:\n\xb5\n\x08\xc0e\xcd\xc0\xc0\xc0\x0e\xc4q@\xcc\x0c\xc4\x16@\xcc\x01\xc4b@\x1c\x08\xc4\xea@,\x08\xc4\x00PK\x01\x02\x14\x00\x14\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\xd5}gK\xc9\xb8\xd0xH\x00\x00\x00\\\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xb6\x81\x00\x00\x00\x00format.npyPK\x01\x02\x14\x00\x14\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\xd5}gKR\xab(\x82I\x00\x00\x00X\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xb6\x81p\x00\x00\x00shape.npyPK\x01\x02\x14\x00\x14\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\xd5}gKy\xea\xf44\x99\x00\x00\x00\xa0\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xb6\x81\xe0\x00\x00\x00data.npyPK\x01\x02\x14\x00\x14\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\xd5}gK\x96\xb0\xb4\xa3]\x00\x00\x00x\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xb6\x81\x9f\x01\x00\x00col.npyPK\x01\x02\x14\x00\x14\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\xd5}gK\r\xef\xd0@_\x00\x00\x00x\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xb6\x81!\x02\x00\x00row.npyPK\x05\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x05\x00\x0f\x01\x00\x00\xa5\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00'
(59, 11)      0.137877385333
(7, 36)       0.137729960685
(94, 14)      0.0951372931412
(3, 80)       0.235640993271
(56, 54)      0.504472012678
(8, 14)       0.657124520803
(22, 92)      0.951629612278
(81, 18)      0.733232743418
(39, 16)      0.228000113182
(17, 15)      0.127198226805
```

Comment: Thank you @sascha!! I'll give this a try!

Comment: `save_npz` writes the attributes of the sparse matrix to a `npz` `zip` archive.  In effect it is saving several numpy arrays in binary form.  I don't think a `pickle` or `json` converter has been defined for sparse matrices.  The `np.array` pickle uses the `np.save` function.

Comment: @hpaulj So you are saying that pickle might not be usable here (using defaults), but the approach i showed is ok?

Comment: I'm having problems sending bytes through an http request. They say that cant be converted to 'utf-8' some characters: `{UnicodeDecodeError}'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xea in position 10: invalid continuation byte`

Comment: It is working right now: I had to encode base64 the bytes to send them as JSON. Thank you so much both

Comment: @JuanAguilarGuisado I totally forgot that, despite not giving JSON details! Good point!